# Is there Audio steganalysis tools based MP3 format?

Tags: audio, steganography

I need an audio steganalysis tool for detecting stego mp3 files.
There is an audio steganalysis tools (MP3stego), but its input is for wav stego files. Also there are some audio steganalysis algorithms that refers to MP3stego.

Comment: From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam,"*

Comment: I have not seen any audio steganalysis tool for mp3 format.